# Implementing Bag of Words in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
headers = ['label', 'sms_message']
df = pd.read_csv ('spam.csv', names = headers)
df ['label'] = df['label'].map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})
print (df.head(7))
print (df.shape)
count_vector = CountVectorizer()
#count_vector.fit(df)
y = count_vector.fit_transform(df)
count_vector.get_feature_names()
doc_array = y.toarray()
print (doc_array)
frequency_matrix = pd.DataFrame(doc_array, columns = count_vector.get_feature_names())
frequency_matrix
```

Sample data and output:

```
   label                                        sms_message
0      0  Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only ...
1      0                      Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...
2      1  Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina...
3      0  U dun say so early hor... U c already then say...

(5573, 2)
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]

label   sms_message
0   1   0
1   0   1
```

My Question:

My csv file is basically many rows of sms messages.

I cannot understand why I am getting only output for the column labels and not for the entire rows of sms texts.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass only the sms_message column to count vectorizer as shown below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

docs = ['Tea is an aromatic beverage..',
        'After water, it is the most widely consumed drink in the world',
        'There are many different types of tea.',
        'Tea has a stimulating effect in humans.',
        'Tea originated in Southwest China during the Shang dynasty'] 

df = pd.DataFrame({'sms_message': docs, 'label': np.random.choice([0, 1], size=5)})

cv = CountVectorizer()
counts = cv.fit_transform(df['sms_message'])

df_counts = pd.DataFrame(counts.A, columns=cv.get_feature_names())
df_counts['label'] = df['label']
```

Output:

```
df_counts

Out[26]: 
   after  an  are  aromatic  beverage  ...  types  water  widely  world  label
0      0   1    0         1         1  ...      0      0       0      0      1
1      1   0    0         0         0  ...      0      1       1      1      0
2      0   0    1         0         0  ...      1      0       0      0      1
3      0   0    0         0         0  ...      0      0       0      0      1
4      0   0    0         0         0  ...      0      0       0      0      0

[5 rows x 32 columns]
```

Comment: first thank you.  Second: what does this do "df_counts = pd.DataFrame(counts.A"...I am asking about the "counts.A" part - what does it mean? thx !!!

Comment: counts.A or the equivalent counts.toarray() output a dense matrix representation of the counts for the different terms. Some algorithms like neural networks need a dense array to work with, others can work with the sparse array. In my answer, the counts_df is there so that you can verify the output.

Answer (score 0):

Using @KRKirov answer of passing just the column header ('sms_message) to count vectorizer,
I edited my code and got the right output:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = ['label', 'sms_message']
df = pd.read_csv ('spam.csv', names = headers)
df ['label'] = df['label'].map({'ham': 0, 'spam': 1})
df ["sms_message"]= df["sms_message"].str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s]','')

count_vector = CountVectorizer()
y = count_vector.fit_transform(df['sms_message'])
doc_array = y.toarray()

frequency_matrix = pd.DataFrame(doc_array, columns = count_vector.get_feature_names())
frequency_matrix
```